# Right to left text not working in the "value" and "placeholder" attributes

Tags: html, google-chrome, arabic, right-to-left

only inside the placeholder and value attributes my text doesn't work, in other places it does, here's my markup:

```html
<form method="post" action="#" dir="rtl">
  <textarea name="question" placeholder="پرسیار"></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="firstChoice" placeholder="وه‌ڵامی یه‌كه‌م"/>
  <input type="text" name="secondChoice" placeholder="وه‌ڵامی دووه‌م"/>
  <input type="text" name="thirdChoice" placeholder="وه‌ڵامی سێیه‌م"/>
  <input type="text" name="fourthChoice" placeholder="وه‌ڵامی چواره‌م"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submitQuestion" value="داخڵبكه‌" style="width:52.4%;cursor:pointer;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not see any problem. Do you? http://i.stack.imgur.com/P16sv.png

Comment: it works for me too when i run it in jsfiddle, but not on my pc, what could the problem be associated with ?

Comment: A. Are you using the same browser?. B. Maybe the doctype different. What doctype are you using?

Comment: do you mean <!DOCTYPE html> ? 
 and for the browser i am using chrome.

Comment: Yes, I mean `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Is this what you are using in your app? Is your project has public URL or can you upload it?

Comment: when i upload it to an online editor like "jsfiddle.net", it works, i don't know why but the problem must be with my pc ?

Comment: do you upload all of the html to jsfiddle including head and encoding meta tags etc.? In jsfiddle you can't. try to do this with http://jsbin.com maybe it something with the head. Can you upload a screenshot of your project? Also, post the **full html content** of your page.

Comment: thank you! i forgot the meta charset tag, fixed it.

Comment: Happy to hear :) Good luck..